# updating the cells in a partitioned table using .Q.ind[] in q

Tags: kdb

I have a partitioned table and can read it using a get command as such:
get `:hdb/2018.01.01/trade

and will give me:

```
sym size exchange
-----------------
0   100  2
1   200  2
1   300  2
```

I like to modify the cell value like size from 200 and 300 to a 1000 given an index or list of rows. So I am using

```
.Q.ind[`:hdb/2018.01.01/trade; 1 2j]
```

to get the rows and then change the cell. But I am getting a `rank error when running .Q.ind[].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting is that the first input param to .Q.ind is the mapped table name, not a symbol representing the table name/location

I'm not sure if .Q.ind is going to help you here though, it's more useful for data retrieval than data (re)write.

A couple of approaches you could take:

1. Pull in the whole date slice `select from table where date=X`, modify it in memory and then write it back down using `` `:hdb/2018.01.01/trade/ set delete date from modifiedTable ``. This is assuming you're not modifying any enumerated/symbol columns. You'd have to be careful to maintain same schema, maintain same compression etc
2. Use the dbmaint package to handle the changes: https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb/blob/master/utils/dbmaint.md
3. If you're careful enough you could pull in only the column itself, modify it and write it back down. `` p set @[get p:`:hdb/2018.01.01/trade/col1;1 2;:;1000] ``

Comment: your solution works, but how do you pass the mapped table name. I had it working before, must have got it by trial and error.

Comment: It would be `.Q.ind[trade; 1 2j]`. In other words you pass it by reference, not by (symbol) name

Comment: but that would not work. My table is in the partitioned directory, and some how I have to tell .Q.ind[] where it is.

Comment: Do you have the database (containing the table) loaded? `.Q.ind` assumes the database is loaded into your session. And I mean loaded at the root level of the database, not loaded on a per-date-slice basis as you suggested in your original post

Comment: wouldn't t:get `:hdb/2016.01.01/trade load the table into q session?

Comment: That only loads a single slice (treating it as a standalone splayed table). To properly load the database you'd need to load the entirety of the `hdb` directory. That maps in all slices and allows you to use tools such as `.Q.ind`. But note that all queries on date-partitioned tables now require you to specify a date in the where clause of your selects, i.e. `select from trade where date=2018.01.01`

Answer (score 1):

You could also use an amend operation to update the values.

`` @[`:hdb/2018.01.01/trade;`size;@[;1 2;:;1000] ``

This will edit your table on disk.

```
q)get`:hdb/2018.01.01/trade
sym size exchange
-----------------
0   100  2
1   200  2
1   300  2

q)@[`:hdb/2018.01.01/trade;`size;@[;1 2;:;1000]]
`:hdb/2018.01.01/trade
q)get `:hdb/2018.01.01/trade/
sym size exchange
-----------------
0   100  2
1   1000 2
2   1000 2
```